# Script Task in SSIS Input0Buffer Error

Tags: ssis, vb.net-2010

I need to change existing SSIS package to add new columns. This package has a script task that compares OLD and NEW values. It's giving me bellow errors.

at ScriptComponent_2dc377607ff1474a82d85cf977045c1c.vbproj.ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at ScriptComponent_2dc377607ff1474a82d85cf977045c1c.vbproj.UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

Here is the VB code:

```
   #Region "Private Constants"
        Private Const oldValueTag As String = "OLD"
        Private Const newValueTag As String = "NEW"
        Private Const nullValueTag As String = "_IsNull"
    #End Region

        Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
            Dim column As IDTSInputColumn100
            Dim newColumnName As String
            Dim rowType As Type = Row.GetType()
            Dim newColumnValue As String
            Dim oldColumnValue As String
            Dim newColumnValueNumber As Double
            Dim oldColumnValueNumber As Double


            Row.RecordChanged = False

                'Loop through list of Input Columns per Row
                For Each column In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection

                    'Reset Values to defaults
                    newColumnValue = ""
                    oldColumnValue = ""
                    newColumnValueNumber = 0
                    oldColumnValueNumber = 0

                    If column.Name.EndsWith(oldValueTag) Then

                        'Set NEW column name based on OLD
                        newColumnName = column.Name.Substring(0, column.Name.IndexOf(oldValueTag)) + newValueTag

                        'Check if our OLD value is Null - grab value
                        If CBool(rowType.GetProperty(column.Name & nullValueTag).GetValue(Row, Nothing)) = False Then
                            oldColumnValue = Trim(rowType.GetProperty(column.Name).GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString)
                        End If

                        If CBool(rowType.GetProperty(newColumnName & nullValueTag).GetValue(Row, Nothing)) = False Then
                        newColumnValue = Trim(rowType.GetProperty(newColumnName).GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString)


         End If

                  If Double.TryParse(oldColumnValue, oldColumnValueNumber) And Double.TryParse(newColumnValue, newColumnValueNumber) Then

                       If Not oldColumnValueNumber = newColumnValueNumber Then
                            Row.RecordChanged = True
                            Return
                        End If

                    Else

                        If Not oldColumnValue = newColumnValue Then
                            Row.RecordChanged = True
                            Return
                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: Could anyone please guide me on how to check those fields that pass nulls?

Comment: Has this code ever worked?

Comment: Yes. It works. But I got the error when I added new columns.

Comment: In the Columns tab, have you clicked on the ones you are updating to indicate they are ReadWrite? Default is ReadOnly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption made in your code is that the inputrow contains a NEW column for each OLD column. My guess is that you have added an OLD column without a corresponding NEW column.

You need to pass to the component something like

Column1OLD
 
Column2OLD
Column3OLD
Column1NEW
Column2NEW
Column3NEW

I suggest:

1. Check if you pass an equal number of OLD and NEW columns.
2. Check if there are any spelling differences within pairs of OLD and NEW columns.

Comment: Thanks you. Exactly this was the error. 2. Check if there are any spelling differences within pairs of OLD and NEW columns.